# Why does this code not work very well?

Tags: python

```
#This will import time, so that I can break between lines
import time
import random
import os
#This will open the file, and will allow me to print it out
words =open("Words.txt", "r+")
print(words.read())
#This sets the different words to variables
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
grid = 0

for i in words:
     list_of_words[x] = i.rstrip()
     x = x +1
     grid = [words[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]
for x,y,z in grid:
     print(x,y,z)
#This will close the word file
words.close
```

I've got the first part to work, but when it comes up to the second part it says I have to have an `int` in it. This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jamie\Documents\Jamie\Homework\Computing\Coureswork\Computer Science Courseword real.py", line 18, in <module>
    for x,y,z in grid:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Why do you initialise `grid`, which you later assign a list comprehension to, as `0`? That's just asking for trouble. Note also that, by the time you get to `for i in words` you've *already read the whole file*, so there's nothing left to iterate over.

Comment: Right, basically, I have to make a 3 by 3 grid with the 5 letter words from the file, I then also have to put them into variables and those are the ones that I am trying to put in to the grid.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question; if `grid` is going to be a list, why not start with `grid = []`?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help i'v made it so it does not come up with that error message

Comment: Next time, btw, try to follow the rules in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get a question less likely to attract downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is because `grid` is `0` (which you initialized it to), rather than becoming a list when you assign a list comprehension to that name in the first loop.

That loop never does anything because you've already consumed the `words` file with `words.read()` near the top of the program. Iterating over the file does nothing, since you're already at the end. In order to read the file again, you either need to close and reopen it, or use `words.seek(0)` to rewind your position in the file. Or better yet, don't read the whole thing into a string if you don't need to.

Note that even after you fix the issue with reading the file, you'll have other problems. For instance, you've never defined `list_of_words`, so that will cause an exception. You're also trying to slice the file in the list comprehension you're assigning to `grid`. That's not legal.

Comment: Thank for your help it is working fine now I modified the code and now i'v got the 3 by 3 grid